# clp appends bytes to output

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I am migrating a number of databases to UTF-8, and just discovered phenomena that I was not aware of. When selecting data out to the terminal, additional bytes are added to the output. Example:

```
~]$ x=$(db2 -x "values 'a'")
~]$ echo "${x}b"
a b
```

One additional space after a

```
~]$ x=$(db2 -x "values 'aa'")
echo "${x}b"
aa  b
```

Two additional space after aa

It does not seem to matter how many bytes a character occupies in utf8:

```
~]$ x=$(db2 -x "values ''")
~]$ echo "${x}b"
 b
```

One additional space after g-clef

```
~]$ x=$(db2 -x "values ''")
~]$ echo "${x}b"
  b
```

Two additional space after g-clef g-clef

db cfg:

```
Database territory                                      = SE
Database code page                                      = 1208
Database code set                                       = UTF8
Database country/region code                            = 46
Database collating sequence                             = SYSTEM_819_SE
```

The terminal has encoding UTF8 (tried terminator and gnome-terminal), and before connecting to the database I did:

```
export LC_CTYPE=sv_SE.utf8
```

The above is of course just silly examples, but I have a fair amount of tests in scripts similar to that:

```
dbtype=`db2 -x "values nya.get_db_type()"`
if [ "${dbtype}" = "N" ]; then
    ...
```

where I need to change the test one way or another.

Any thoughts on a configuration, that would get rid of the extra bytes?

```
~]$ uname -a
Linux nya-ladok3-release 3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Dec 2 08:31:54 EST 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
~]$ db2level
DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable: 
"db2inst1") uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL11050" with level 
identifier "0601010F".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v11.5.0.0", "s1906101300", "DYN1906101300AMD64", 
and Fix Pack "0".
Product is installed at "/opt/ibm/db2/V11.5".
```

Comment: I suspect it's a CLP "feature", so no amount of database configuration changes would help.

Comment: Thanks, I'll start wading through git to find candidates to change

Comment: I was able to reproduce it on 10.5 as well, looks like the CLP is incorrectly padding strings containing multibyte characters -- it formats columns for output using their byte lengths, not character lengths. You might consider opening a defect. Run, for example, `db2 -x "values ('a','b'),('b','b')"` and then `db2 -x "values ('a','b'),('','b')"`.

Comment: I have opened a PMR, I'll report back the outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the explanation I got from IBM support, I have not tested it myself, but it seems reasonable. The workaround suggested will work for all situations that I can think of right now:

The extra spaces padded in CLP is the expected behavior. This is because there are some multiple-byte characters that take more than 1-physical space. See below example that demonstrates the same:

Say, U+FF2D FULLWIDTH LATIN CAPITAL LETTER M

```
$ db2 "select a, hex(a) from table(values('A' || u&'\FF2D' || 'B'),('A B')) t(a)"
A   2     
----- ----------
AＭB 41EFBCAD42 —> Here wide-M is taking more space than a normal multi/single byte character. 
A B  41204220202 record(s) selected.
```

If you are using a lot of functions like get_db_type() in your scripts, you can change the return value in these functions to modify it to OCTETS:

Something like the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_db_type()
RETURNS VARCHAR(1 OCTETS)
DETERMINISTIC NO EXTERNAL ACTION CONTAINS SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
    RETURN 'N';

END @
```

I'll leave the current workaround as is below:

If nothing else shows up I'll probably do something along the lines of:

```
x=$(db2 -x "values ('')")
x="${x%"${x##*[![:space:]]}"}"
echo ${x}b
b
```

At first, I figured:

```
x=$(db2 -x "values ('')" | xargs echo)
```

would do, but the pipe introduces a subshell, so:

```
echo ${x}b
SQL1024N A database connection does not exist. SQLSTATE=08003b
```

it does not work.